# Typescript: How to extract only the optional keys from a type?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type like this:

```
type User = {
  uid: string,
  displayName?: string,
  bestFriend?: string,
}
```

Is it possible to extract the optional properties from my User type using a
mapped type of some kind? I'm looking for how to define the
`OptioanlProperties<T>` type below.

```
type OptionalUserProperties = OptionalProperties<User>
// type OptionalUserProperties = "displayName" | "bestFriend"
```

My use-case is to compute an `UpdateOf<User>` type that permits specific
"operation" values, like `DeleteProperty` to be assigned to keys that are optional in the base type.

```
export type UpdateOf<T> =
  // optional fields may be their own type, or the special DeleteProperty type.
  { [P in OptionalProperties<T>]?: T[P] | DeleteProperty } &
  // required fields may be changed, but cannot be deleted.
  { [P in Diff<keyof T, OptionalProperties<T>>]?: T[P] }
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes:

```
type OptionalPropertyOf<T extends object> = Exclude<{
  [K in keyof T]: T extends Record<K, T[K]>
    ? never
    : K
}[keyof T], undefined>
```

Comment: This is much more concise than the solution in the linked duplicate question. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed this solution feels better as well.

Comment: This is amazing what one can do with TypeScript! I needed this to improve my [`ModifyDeep`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74216680/985454) to allow changing of property optionality of an existing type.