# Typescript combine types "keyof X" & SomeType

Tags: typescript

I want to define some type which is key of some other type. It is possible to do this

```
interface B {
   x: something;
   y: string;
   z: something;
}

type keyOfB = keyof B;

export class A {
    foo: keyOfB;
}
```

But at same time i want to foo be only some type eg string or something, how to combine it?

```
foo: keyOfB & type
```

doesnt work.

Theoretically it is job for Pick<> or Extract<> but i cant make it working

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: try use ```|``` instead of ```&```

Comment: hm thx, syntactically it is correct, no error thrown however it let also define non that type key

Comment: @luky I think an example of the expected behavior would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i modified the answer posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53899815

to this and it seems to work :)

```
type KeyOfType<T extends object, Type> = Exclude<{
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Type
      ? K
      : never
  }[keyof T], undefined>
```

usage:

```
interface B {
   x: something;
   y: string;
   z: something;
}

export class A {
    foo: KeyOfType<B, string>;
}
```

Foo prop will be only allowed to assign key of B that are type of string. (only 'y' in this case)