# Create sub interface with all optional fields of an interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface containing some optional fields

```
interface Config {
  name: string,
  context?: string,
  value?: number,
  type: string
}
```

I would like to extract all optional fields and their values

The result should look like this:

```
type OptionalConfig = ExtractOptionalProperties<Config>

// {
//   context?: string,
//   value?: number,
// }
```

I found a way to [extract all optional keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53899692/typescript-how-to-extract-only-the-optional-keys-from-a-type) but have no idea how to extract also the values. Is it possible with Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) for that:

```typescript
type ExtractOptionalProperties<T extends object> = {
    [key in OptionalPropertyOf<T>]: T[key];
}
```

`T[key]` is what gives you the property type.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwAoCcmR1BgDMAeAFSggA9gIUATAZyiQCMArCAY2AD4oAXigBRatwwBXBhFIBvAFBRlUANoBpKAhRQA1hBBJiUcgF0AXCaq16zKACUeSHA1LqANCY2m+Slf4B+KBQIADcIHD9-ZUt1BQBfVX1DYzNPSUYIYm0IBj4AbgUFbTocYjRuaABhVGyAcyhFf3QAWwhLJmAcbTr3KKhuVDpaAI6unr7-UMxJCFHgyRa2CMmVUEgx7pQ6hKL16DEuiuA4RFRMXHwIxAgmCms6RhZ2Ll4BYSaVJIMtHVPkdDYPAEIhkch8CxeZKmQrxPbgaD-c4YGooepCUS0HDHJGAy4ghC3Uio+q+BQyCRoHDQDAQYBQaiWXGYEkIOqFagAOkGKGGwHyUAA9IKoJ0tg0AD5QDIybIhBgKLnTKTQYULJYRKBSmVZHIMIA)

It's also possible to [modify the modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers), although with the `OptionalPropertyOf` from the answer you linked, the optionality has been converted to a union with `undefined`.

You haven't said you do, but **if** you wanted to remove the optionality, you could use `Exclude<T[key], undefined>`:

```typescript
type ExtractOptionalProperties<T extends object> = {
    [key in OptionalPropertyOf<T>]: Exclude<T[key], undefined>;
}
```

In the result, `context` would be `string` instead of `string | undefined`, and `value` would be `number` instead of `number | undefined`. ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwAoCcmR1BgDMAeAFSggA9gIUATAZyiQCMArCAY2AD4oAXigBRatwwBXBhFIBvAFBRlUANoBpKAhRQA1hBBJiUcgF0AXCaq16zKACUeSHA1LqANCY2m+Slf4B+KBQIADcIHD9-ZUt1BQBfVX1DYzNPSUYIYm0IBj4AbgUFbTocYjRuaABhVGyAcyhFf3QAWwhLJmAcbTr3KKhuVDpaAI6unr7-UMxJCFHgyRa2CMmVUEgx7pQ6hKL16DEuiuA4RFRMXHwIxAgmCms6RhZ2Ll4BYSaVJIMtHVPkdDYPAEIhkch8CyicRSGQUb4gUzpTLZEJ5QrxPbgaD-c4YGooepCKFHXg4wGXEEIW6kfH1XwKGQSNA4aAYCDAKDUSxkzC0hB1QrUAB0gxQw2A+SgAHopVBOlsdsLplJoDKFksIkA)) But again, you didn't say you wanted to do that, just wanted to show that there's more you can do if you like.