# How can i overwrite a property type?

Tags: typescript

Given that i have following structure

```
type AB = {
    A: string;
    B: string;
}
```

but now i want to create a new type which extends keys but also overwrite the 'A' property. So final type should be

```
{
    A: number;
    B: string;
}
```

So I tried to assign AB type to my final type and append the 'A' property with new type

```
type final = AB & {A: number};
```

But it doesn't work :(
So my question is; how to extend type to other with changed property type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding interface property type defined in Typescript d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file)

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work," what error message are you receiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but you could use a mapped type to filter out keys that you want to override and then intersect it with override:

```
type Override<T1, T2> = {
    [K in Exclude<keyof T1, keyof T2>]: T1[K]
} & {
    [K in keyof T2]: T2[K]
};

type final = Override<AB, { A: number }>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a simple intersection (`AB & {A: number}`) will not work, because it will make all individual properties intersect separately. It means `A` would need to be of type `string & number`, which is impossible do achieve.

Use this instead:

```
type Overwrite<T, U> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>> & U;
```

Usage:

```
type Final = Overwrite<AB, { A: number }>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type Override<T1, T2> = Omit<T1, keyof T2> & T2;
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Comment: explanation: https://dev.to/vborodulin/ts-how-to-override-properties-with-type-intersection-554l