# Cannot find name 'Omit' in Typescript

Tags: typescript

## Background

I'm making my custom `index.d.ts` file on `src/@types/index.d.ts`.
I needed to merge my type like below.

```
// src/@types/index.d.ts
declare namespace Admin {
  interface InitialStateFromDB {
    teamSettings: {
      teamPasswords: TeamPassword[],
      teamCount: number
    },
    adminPasswords: string,
    postInfos: PostInfo[] | undefined
  }
  interface InitialState extends Omit<InitialStateFromDB, 'adminPasswords'> {
    adminPasswords: AdminPassword
  }
}
```

## Problem

I got error : `Cannot find name 'Omit'.ts(2304)` by VSCode Intellisense. But compile worked well.

So, I made Omit type `type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>` (copied in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53936938/9279003))

And after compile, I got another error : `'Omit' was also declared here.`

What should I do in this case? Just ignore IntelliSense's error ?

Comment: Did you try restarting VSCode? I sometimes get typing errors which disappear after a restart.

Comment: @Mathyn yes I did, but same error.

Comment: Are you sure VSCode and your compiler use the same Typescript version?

Comment: @Mathyn No, VSCode use 3.4.5, mine is 3.5.1

Comment: Do you get compile errors if you compile with version 3.4.5?

Comment: @Mathyn Yes, but now I fix my problem by matching VSCode's typescript version with mine. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`Omit` was only recently [added in TS 3.5.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#the-omit-helper-type) so you may be using an older version of TS in your workspace that does not support it yet.

Make sure your VS Code workspace is using the same version of TypeScript you are compiling with by following [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-the-workspace-version-of-typescript). Just open a TS file run the `Select TypeScript Version` command in VS Code, and opt to use your workspace version of TypeScript (which should be 3.5.1)

Comment: I am facing tough time with a plugin which is showing same error, can you please help me, i tried everything

Answer (score 9):

try using "skipLibCheck": true as one of compilerOptions in your tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 4):

Use typescript version 3.5.x

And if you are using Angular version 6, then upgrade it to 8.2.2

You can check following package versions in `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@material/dialog": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-charts": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-diagrams": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-diagrams": "^17.4.51",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
    "yarn": "^1.6.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.116",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.1",
    "@types/xml2js": "^0.4.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why "using typescript version 3.5.x" maybe with documentation link. Could you also format correctly your answer. The "dependencies" blob is currently useless and unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

Press ctrl + shift + p in vscode and type TypeScript and select "TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version"

Comment: consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Thanks man, but i'm new here, i still can't comment

Comment: It is only a matter of time till you gain those privileges