# How to inherit PromiseLike interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, promise

I want to extend the PromiseLike interface.

(I use TypeScript v3.6.3)

I took the original PromiseLike interface:

```
interface PromiseLike<T> {
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(
        onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null,
        onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null,
    ): PromiseLike<TResult1 | TResult2>
}
```

then I only inherit PromiseLike and replace nested PromiseLike types to Thenable:

```
interface Thenable<T = any> extends PromiseLike<T> {
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(
        onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | Thenable<TResult1>) | undefined | null,
        onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | Thenable<TResult2>) | undefined | null,
    ): Thenable<TResult1 | TResult2>
}
```

and got this error:

```
Error:(28, 18) TS2430: Interface 'Thenable<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'PromiseLike<T>'.
  Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
    Type '<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: T) => TResult1 | Thenable<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | Thenable<TResult2>) => Thenable<TResult1 | TResult2>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) => PromiseLike<TResult1 | TResult2>'.
      Types of parameters 'onrejected' and 'onrejected' are incompatible.
        Type 'TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>' is not assignable to type 'TResult2 | Thenable<TResult2>'.
          Type 'PromiseLike<TResult2>' is not assignable to type 'TResult2 | Thenable<TResult2>'.
            Type 'PromiseLike<TResult2>' is not assignable to type 'Thenable<TResult2>'.
              Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
                Type '<TResult1 = TResult2, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: TResult2) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) => PromiseLike<TResult1 | TResult2>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = TResult2, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: TResult2) => TResult1 | Thenable<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | Thenable<TResult2>) => Thenable<TResult1 | TResult2>'.
                  Types of parameters 'onrejected' and 'onrejected' are incompatible.
                    Type 'TResult2 | Thenable<TResult2>' is not assignable to type 'TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>'.
                      Type 'Thenable<TResult2>' is not assignable to type 'TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>'.
                        Type 'Thenable<TResult2>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<TResult2>'.
                          Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
                            Type '<TResult1 = TResult2, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: TResult2) => TResult1 | Thenable<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | Thenable<TResult2>) => Thenable<TResult1 | TResult2>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = TResult2, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: TResult2) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) => PromiseLike<TResult1 | TResult2>'.
                              Types of parameters 'onrejected' and 'onrejected' are incompatible.
                                Type 'TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>' is not assignable to type 'TResult2 | Thenable<TResult2>'.
                                  Type 'PromiseLike<TResult2>' is not assignable to type 'TResult2 | Thenable<TResult2>'.
```

How to fix this error?

Further, I would like to extend this interface like this:

```
export interface Thenable<T = any> extends PromiseLike<T> {
    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(
        onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | ThenableOrIteratorOrValue<TResult1>) | undefined | null,
        onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | ThenableOrIteratorOrValue<TResult2>) | undefined | null,
    ): ThenableOrIteratorOrValue<TResult1 | TResult2>
}
```

and I want it to remain compatible with PromiseLike, so that async await functions are compatible with it.

Comment: You cannot extend an interface and overwrite a property. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file

Comment: Why do you want to extend the PromiseLike interface? What do you try to achieve? Thanks

Comment: I implemented synchronous version of async functions using generator (yield instead await). I use Iterator type as synchronous Promise. And now I want to combine all promise like interfaces.

Comment: Would a `union` type be of helpful? I don't know your code for your `ThenableOrIteratorOrValue<T>`. Maybe something like the following could help you: `type PromiseLikeOrThenable<T> = PromiseLike<T> | Thenable<T> | IteratorResult<T>;`

Answer (score 1):

Remaining compatible with `PromiseLike` means that your `Thenable` could be passed as a parameter to a code that expects `PromiseLike`, and that code still should work. For that to work, `then` should accept `onfulfilled` callback which returns `PromiseLike`, not your `Thenable` - because that's the type of callback that the code that uses `PromiseLike` will pass to your implementation of `then`.

So, adding `PromiseLike` to a union of types that could be returned by the callback like this makes the error go away:

```
    onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null,
```

For reasons that I don't understand, `onrejected` is compatible as is, apparently because it's type is not dependent on generic parameter `T`.