# Overwrite generated typescript .d.ts file (React)

Tags: reactjs, types, typescript-typings

I'm using `declaration: true` as part of my TypeScript configuration. It generates the correct types for this component, but I wanted to overwrite it. How would I go about doing that?

```
// Button.tsx

export const Button: React.FC<{
  className: string;
  text: string
}> = ({ className, text }) => (
  <button class={className}>
    {text}
  </button>
)
```

What I've already tried was to place an adjacent `index.d.ts` file in this directory. I thought because of how definition files were resoluted, it would overwrite the export from `Button.tsx`:

```
// index.d.ts

export { default } from "./Button";
```

It references this type definition that I have in this folder as well:

```
// Button.d.ts
declare const Button: any;
export default Button;
```

However, this does not work. Instead, I get the types that I defined from `Button.tsx` - how can I overwrite this type myself?

Comment: [may be this answer will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file)