# TypeScript Parameter Defintion Overrides

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using [@types/react-simple-maps](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-simple-maps), and in one of their type definitions:

```js
interface GeographiesChildrenArgument {
    geographies: object[];
    path: GeoPath;
    projection: GeoProjection;
}
```

they use `object[]`

Now, when I try to use these definitions, I have to do something like this:

```js
{({ geographies }): React.ReactNodeArray => geographies.map(
  (geo: object) => (
    ...
```

is there a way I could make object more specific? If I try:

```js
{({ geographies }: { geographies: GeographyType[] }): React.ReactNodeArray => geographies.map(
  (geo: GeographyType) => (
    ...
```

but then I get the following error:

```
Type '({ geographies }: { geographies: GeographyType[]; }) => React.ReactNodeArray' is not assignable to type '((data: GeographiesChildrenArgument) => void) | (((data: GeographiesChildrenArgument) => void) & string) | (((data: GeographiesChildrenArgument) => void) & number) | ... 5 more ... | undefined'.
Type '({ geographies }: { geographies: GeographyType[]; }) => React.ReactNodeArray' is not assignable to type '(data: GeographiesChildrenArgument) => void'.
Types of parameters '__0' and 'data' are incompatible.
Type 'GeographiesChildrenArgument' is not assignable to type '{ geographies: GeographyType[]; }'.
Types of property 'geographies' are incompatible.
Type 'object[]' is not assignable to type 'GeographyType[]'.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'GeographyType': type, geometry, propertiests (2322)
index.d.ts(95, 5): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & GeographiesProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

So, is there a way to override `object[]` to be my object definition: `GeographyType[]`?

Comment: full code is available here: https://github.com/kennethbigler/react-home/blob/master/src/components/resume/travel-map/WorldMap.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a silly answer, but the final solution was that I just contributed to `@types/react-simple-maps` changing `object` to `any` as it is recommended in their guidelines to use `any` over `object` as `object` is too restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to extend interface. You can't change the type of existing property. 
Something like this below. Let me know if it works.
Also check this out it's about modifying existing types [Overriding interface property type defined in Typescript d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file)

```
 {({ geographies }: { geographies: object[] extends GeographyType[] }): React.ReactNodeArray => 
  geographies.map(
   (geo: GeographyType) => (
  ...
```

Comment: I tried that one, you get this error if you try that: ```Type '({ geographies }: { geographies: any; }) => React.ReactNodeArray' is not assignable to type '(geographies: object[], projection: GeoProjection) => void'.```