# Typescript override deep key

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's say I have an interface like this one

```js
interface Theme {
  a: {
    b?: {
      c: CustomType;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

how do I override this theme interface into a new one changing b to always defined?? (Removing `?`) obviously I'd like to keep everything else the same.

EDIT: I don't have access to `CustomType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
type NewTheme = Theme & {
  a: {
    b: NonNullable<Theme['a']['b']>
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAsIFsUG8BQyycAXMgUUQEYD8ZFlRCZAzmFKAOYDchlAvn0GD8YAJ4AHFADkIAdwzYUAXjSYcyAGTk%20pHYyplpAexDSArgBtLcKpYgAeRTgDaAcjhuAuu6reAfEL4gkA)

Answer (score 0):

Because `parameter?: type` is a shorthand for `parameter: type | undefined` you can [override interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286276/5062890):

```
interface Theme1 extends Theme {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: CustomType;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this remove all the other theme properties?

Comment: Plus I don't have access to CustomType

Comment: This method keeps all the other `theme` properties but not for you if haven't access to `CustomType`.