# How to overwrite property for intersection type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, .d.ts

Let's say I have these types:

```js
type BaseAnimal = {
  species: string
  owner: boolean
}

type Cat = BaseAnimal & {
  species: 'cat'
  hasTail: boolean
}

type Dog = BaseAnimal & {
  species: 'dog'
  likesWalks: boolean
}

type Animal = Cat | Dog
```

And I want to create a type called `AnimalParams`, which is identical to `Animal` **except the `owner` property, which is a string.**

I can't do either of the below.

```js
// This seems to keep the owner property from Animal instead of overwriting
// So it raises an error if I try to specify owner as a string
type AnimalParams = Animal & {
  owner: string
}

// This strips away properties unique to Cat or Dog
// So it raises an error if I try to specify hasTail or likesWalks
type AnimalParams = Omit<Animal, 'owner'> & {
  owner: string
}
```

Now, the only workaround I can think of is to do as below, but this seems unnecessarily repetitive. Is there a cleaner, more concise way?

```js
type CatParams = Omit<Cat, 'owner'> & {
  owner: string
}

type DogParams = Omit<Dog, 'owner'> & {
  owner: string
}

type AnimalParams = CatParams | DogParams
```

I read a few SO threads on utility types (such as [Overriding interface property type defined in Typescript d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41285211/11249670), which was for interfaces), but couldn't find what I needed. Thanks for any answers in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of manually omitting `owner` prop from each type, you can use [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type OmitOwner<T = Animal> = T extends BaseAnimal ? Omit<T, 'owner'> : never;

type AnimalParams = OmitOwner & {
  owner: string
};
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
(Omit<Cat, 'owner'> & { owner: string; }) 
  | (Omit<Dog, 'owner'> & { owner: string; })
```

That's due to automatic distribution over union types

> Instantiation of `T extends U ? X : Y` with the type argument `A | B | C` for `T` is resolved as `(A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y)`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgQQHYEsC2cA2UC8UA3gLABQUUCkAxuhAgFxXABO6qA5uZQPYDuqCK2YAjXrxwQ4qcgF9y5UJCgBhOMAKxEKDNjwAyYjyq16TKAHIaGyyYAWiACpx0OMRKkz5issugAIrycWvBIaFi4UEakFKYQdAzMlgAmwXZxOOgA1gwA6rjZFuKS0rJkCmRK4NAR+lrqmgA+UEHcVX41UADymOjA3YLCADxOWnW4AHxaYxAAHsAQqCkI2uF6UQD8PX3AowA0VgJCrJbTzEIAbsIA3L7+UBM4AApwrHCYq4S9-YMn0cY4sdhMwEGwOO05DcgA)

---

#### Why original attempt doesn't work?

`keyof` union produces intersection of keys of types in union, so

```
type AnimalKeys = keyof Animal // is "species" | "owner"
```

And implementation of `Omit` is:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

Comment: This was eye-opening. Thanks so much!

For anyone referencing this question - I recommend that also you read the linked docs. Basically, "an instantiation of `T extends U ? X : Y `with the type argument `A | B | C` for `T` is resolved as `(A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y)`".

Answer (score 7):

I have been using this generic for overwriting props in react with success:

```
type Overwrite<T, NewT> = Omit<T, keyof NewT> & NewT;

export type TouchableAvatarPropTypes = Overwrite<AvatarPropTypes, {
    /** Function executed when avatar is pressed. */
    onPress: () => void;
    /** Size of the avatar */
    size: number;
}>
```

You can do some pretty clean one-liners for exporting.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to stick to types instead of interfaces, you could use generics to avoid the repitition:

```
type BaseAnimalParams<T extends BaseAnimal> = Omit<T, 'owner'> & {
    owner: string;
}

type AnimalParams = BaseAnimalParams<Dog> | BaseAnimalParams<Cat>;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm accepting the other answer because it's more DRY (avoids manually creating another union type), but you also have my upvote.

Comment: Yeah, totally agree. Hadn't thought of using distributive conditional types.

Comment: I like this solution because it can also be nicely generalized, see e.g. `Modify` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55032655/3779853