# Typescript how to add properties to Object constructor?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I need to add properties to  `Object.constructor` on a specific class.

I am Using `lib.es5.d.ts`

I have tried overriding the global Object like:

```
type EntityConstructor = Function & {behaviors: string[]}

declare global {
  interface Object {
    constructor: EntityConstructor
  }
}
```

This throws an error:

```
Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  
Property 'constructor' must be of type 'Function', but here has type 'EntityConstructor'.
```

I don't need this to be an override it could be for a explicit class.

USAGE EXAMPLE:
To clarify why and how I want this property...

I am using [typescript mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html)

I have a method that takes a set of `ConstrainedMixin` constructors, applies them to a base class to create a new Constructor for the mixed class. Then I want to store the list of applied mixin names on that new constructor as a new property. This looks like:

```
import compose from 'lodash.flowright';
export type ConstrainedMixin<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
class Entity {
  static behaves(...behaviors: Array<ConstrainedMixin>){
    const newEnt = compose.apply(
      null,
      behaviors,
    )(Entity);

    newEnt.behaviors = behaviors.map((behaviorClass) => behaviorClass.name);

    return newEnt;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you'd use such a thing?  Is this different from just giving your explicit class some `static` properties?

Comment: @jcalz have added a usage example

Comment: Why can't you just add an instance field `behaviors: string[]` to `Entity`? If you are asking the question _"How can change the global object constructor's type?"_ then you are probably doing the _really_ hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
type EntityConstructor = Function & {behaviors: string[]}

declare global {
  interface O extends Object {
    constructor: EntityConstructor
  }
}
```

But you would need to create another class that extends `Object`. As far as I can tell, there's not really a way to do what you are asking without changing the original `Object` interface itself / the d.ts file or creating a separate class that extends `Object`.

Here are some helpful answers on a related question on [Overriding Interface Property Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file)