# How to add field correctly in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a json object on which I need to add additional field inside a array field in typescript. I am using

```
import **myJson** from 'myJson.json';

for(let i= 0; i < myJson["some_other_fields"].length; ++i) {
  myJson["some_other_fields"][i]["newField"] = "someValue";
}
```

The content of myJson.json looks as below

```
{
   "some_other_fields":[
      {
         "a":"1",
         "b":"2"
      },
      {
         "a":"3",
         "b":"4"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am seeing a error Property 'newField' does not exist on type ' whats the correct way of setting field, do I need to create object {[k: string]: any} and copy field into it?

Comment: Is this pseudo code or is `**myJson**` the actual import?

Comment: If you have a specific, named property like this example which you wish to add then there are ways to [override an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file) (or rather, construct a new interface from the types of an existing one). If your question is 'how to add any additional type to an object' then you've already provided your answer. The imported JSON can be assigned to a variable and given a generic indexed type.

Comment: @Dom its actual import.