# Typescript merge two interfaces

Tags: typescript

> ***UPDATE*** 
> **i found this solution**
>
> ```
> type Merge<T, U> = {
>   [K in keyof T | keyof U]: K extends keyof U? U[K]: K extends keyof T? T[K]: never;
> };
> ```

is there something like this in typescript?(spread operator)

```
type Merge<T, U> = ...[K in keyof T]: T[K], ...[K in keyof U]: U[K]
```

**my task is to Merge two types into a new type. Keys of the second type overrides keys of the first type.**
for example:

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  role: "admin" | "moderator" | "user";
  occupation: string;
}
interface User2 {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: boolean;
}

type mergedType = Merge<User, User2>
```

after merge, interface type will be something like this->

```
{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: boolean;
  role: "admin" | "moderator" | "user";
  occupation: string;
}
```

Comment: `age: boolean`??

Comment: just an example

Comment: @namizo - It makes a big difference, because if `age` has type `number` in one of them and type `boolean` in the other, it markedly complicates merging.

Comment: task says: Keys of the second type overrides keys of the first type. if type of age was number in first interface and boolean in second, age: boolean should be final result

Comment: What do you want to see if the properties from the second type are optional?  What should `Merge<{a: string}, {a?: number}>` be?

Comment: See the linked question for more info, using that solution here gives [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WJ435N).  There are a lot of caveats around index signatures, optional properties, unknown properties, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the types were never in conflict, it would be just be `User & User2`, but in your example `User` has `age: number` and `User2` has `age: boolean`, so they conflict.

You can handle that the way you've said you want to (using the second one's definition) with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) using a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to pick the property type from `B` if it's there or from `A` if it isn't, [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with the second type you're merging:

```typescript
type MergeTypes<A, B> = {
    [key in keyof A]: key extends keyof B ? B[key] : A[key];
} & B;
```

(Edit: Or the rather simpler `type MergeTypes<A, B> = Omit<A, keyof B> & B;` as pointed out by [M. Erim Tuzcuoglu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71101999/157247) and [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file). Doh!)

Usage:

```typescript
type MergedType = MergeTypes<User, User2>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHLAAmAXMumFKAOYDc+hIcAthOZdSPYwXDe2QgAriwBG0BoWRQA9gBtBAIjjEWoJcgA+yJS1nFocMLKiadS4ZjNTCshAmEAHY8FkgOVWgwC+uUJCwiCgY0ABMOLxEZBRe3LYEzGyeXDzS-IIi4pJRsmAAFtDkYrIKEHAgvri4YACeTigAstACACr1EOgAPACCADTIAEIAfMgAvJHSANoA1hC1RCDIc7WyMMg9ALrkK8gQAB6QIMToy-NrQ8gA-EOz85vI5D13tZu+yABkQwy4imDI+3IzSgbQ63VCUAGELCowmeGkJHISn2Sj6USSyhRaPSAnIABYwtjCHJFEjVOoQKjcg5nK53EisbkCkVkFRhBA0T46EA)

Here's how that works:

- `key in keyof A` says that the mapped type will have a key for each key of the type `A`
- `key extends keyof B` checks to see if the key is also a key of type `B`

  - If it is, we use `B[key]` as the property type; if it isn't, we use `A[key]`
- The result of the above only has the properties that `A` has (but with `B`'s type for them if they both have it), it won't have ones that only exist on `B`. So we add `& B` at the end to add them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file)

Here is a working example:

```
interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  role: "admin" | "moderator" | "user";
  occupation: string;
}
interface User2 {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: boolean;
}

type Modify<T, R> = Omit<T, keyof R> & R;

var x: Modify<User, User2> = {id: '123', name: 'name', age: true, occupation: 'occ', role: 'admin'};
console.log(x);
```

Comment: `Omit<T, keyof R>` *headslap* Yes, I should have thought of that instead of a mapped conditional type. (This question is **almost** a duplicate of that one...)