# Typescript interface merging to make an external lib's interface property more specific

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using a function from an external library that returns an object where there is a particular property that is typed as `number`, but since it operates on my data, I know it is in fact just an union of `1 | 2`. How can I override it to be more specific?

```
/* original type: */ { id?: number }
/*  desired type: */ { id: keyof typeof CHAINS_ENUM }
```

###### `src/myFile.ts`

```
import { someFunction, setIds} from '@some-library/core'

setIds([1, 2]) // <- simplification
const { id } = someFunction() // id: number
```

###### `node_modules/@some-library/core/dist/index.d.ts`

```
export { someFunction } from './provider'
```

###### `node_modules/@some-library/core/dist/provider.d.ts`

```
import { SomeInterface } from './types';
export declare function someFunction(key?: string): SomeInterface<T>;
```

###### `node_modules/@some-library/core/dist/types.d.ts`

```
export interface AnotherInterface { ... }
export interface SomeInterface<T = any> extends AnotherInterface {
  id?: number
}
```

---

Simplified code snippet with the actual library in question:

```
import { useWeb3React } from '@web3-react/core'

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const { chainId } = useWeb3React()      // chainId: number
  return <MyForm baseChainId={chainId} /> // type 'number' is not assignable to type 0 | 1 ; baseChainId: keyof typeof CHAINS_ENUM
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish it was possible to override this on a global level, without having to remember to import the library from a different location, but at least it works.

###### `src/utils/web3.ts`

```
import { useWeb3React as useWeb3React_ } from '@web3-react/core'

export const useWeb3React: < T = any >(key?: string) => Modify<
  ReturnType<typeof useWeb3React_<T>>,
  { chainId: SupportedChainIds }
> = useWeb3React_ as any

declare global {
  type SupportedChainIds = 1 | 4
}
```

In the desired file

```
// import { useWeb3React } from '@web3-react/core' // before
import { useWeb3React } from 'src/utils/web3'      // after

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const { chainId } = useWeb3React()      // chainId: 1 | 4
  return <MyForm baseChainId={chainId} /> // no error ✔
}
```

#### `Modify<Original, Newtype>` type

[Overriding interface property type defined in Typescript d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file/55032655#55032655)