# Assigning an additional type to an object property

Tags: node.js, typescript

Consider the following type:

```
type myType = {
  a: string,
  b: string
}
```

Let's say, that at one point of my script, a function could take a `myType` object, but can work with the `a` property as a `number` also. To make this new type for my function I could write:

```
type myNewType = Omit<myType, 'a'> & {
  a: string | number
}
```

Is there any shorter way to write this? I tried with  simply extending the base object, like this:

```
type myNewType = myType & {
  a: number
}
```

but that results in `a` being identified as `string & number` instead of `string | number`.

Comment: From this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file it appears that using Omit is still the conventional wisdom, but others have built utility types on top of the Omit approach which is perhaps semantically cleaner https://stackoverflow.com/a/55032655/9987590