# Use props from various interfaces, without naming them explicitly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Assuming I have this

```
interface ButtonProps {
    children?: React.ReactNode,
    backgroundColor?: Colors,
    style?: object,
    disabled?: boolean,
    classes?: string
    onClick?: () => void
}


const Button = ({
                        backgroundColor,
                        classes,
                        children,
                        disabled = false,
                        onClick,
                        style,
                    }: ButtonProps) => {

    const _constructInlineStyles = (): CSSProperties => {
        ...
    }

    return (
        <button
            className={clsx(classes, 'button-container')}
            disabled={disabled}
            onClick={onClick}
            style={...}>
                {children}
        </button>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

I then want to create a `TextButton` which uses builds on top of `Button`.

```
    interface TextButtonProps {
        children: string;
    }
    
    const TextButton = ({
                            children,
                        }: TextButtonProps) => {
        return (
            <Button>
                <Text>
                    {children}
                </Text>
            </Button>
        )
    }

export default TextButton;
```

Can one write it in a way, that the `ButtonProps` are made available to `TextButton`, without naming them. So instead of

```
    interface TextButtonProps {
        children: string;
    }
    
    const TextButton = ({
                            children,
                            backgroundColor,
                            classes,
                            disabled = false,
                            onClick,
                            style,
                        }: TextButtonProps & ButtonProps ) => {
        return (
            <Button
                 className={classes}
                 disabled={disabled}
                 onClick={onClick}
                 style={style}>
                <Text>
                    {children}
                </Text>
            </Button>
        )
    }
```

Something like

```
    interface TextButtonProps {
        children: string;
        props: ButtonProps;
    }
    
    const TextButton = ({
                            children,
                            props,
                        }: TextButtonProps) => {
        return (
            <Button
                 {...props}>
                <Text>
                    {children}
                </Text>
            </Button>
        )
    }
```

So that I can do

```
<TextButton 
    disabled={true} >
    Fooo
</TextButton>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spread operator to receive the remaining props in the function call and to pass them to the Button component. To use the correct children type, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75224632/6548154) answer using Omit:

```js
import { Text} from 'react-native-paper'
interface ButtonProps {
  disabled?: boolean;
  onClick?: () => void;
  children: JSX.Element;
}

const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

interface TextButtonProps extends Omit<ButtonProps, "children"> {
  children: string;
}

const TextButton = ({ children, ...props }: TextButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <Button {...props}>
      <Text>{children}</Text>
    </Button>
  );
};

const example = <TextButton disabled>Hi</TextButton>;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can [extend interfaces](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-extend-interface/) while [omitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file) a property as follows.

```js
interface TextButtonProps extends Omit<ButtonProps, 'children'> {
        children: string;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to omit the `ButtonProps` but passing them through, without naming them!