# Exclude field from array type in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
type Foo = {
  nested:{
    unwanted:string
    wanted:string
  }
}

type Bar = {
  foos: Foo[]
}
```

I would like to exclude `unwanted` from `Foo[]` and get a type back with the new shape in an array.

```
type Excluded = Bar['foos'][number]['nested'] //the leaf type
type DoesntWork = Omit<Bar['foos'][number]['nested'],'unwanted'> //what i tried :(
```

Comment: If I run your code in Typescript it kind of worked.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKA7CBnYCAEwC4MssBXbAdwENtDSCAnAS2wHNML7HiSrDtywBfdOPShIUAEJ0WyNDwBmCPCVgIA2gF0J6KeGgBRAB4BjADaUixJQHkAtm2AAeeS20ByNXDzeutrYlE4ARhAsQd64BMSBADTe1HxM3gB86EA

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file), a working solution could be:

```
interface Foo {
    nested: {
        wanted: string,
        unwanted: string
    }
}

interface Bar {
  foos: Array<Foo>
}

type Modify<T, R> = Omit<T, keyof R> & R;

type FoosWithoutUnwanted = Modify<Foo, {
    nested: {
        wanted: string
    }
}>

type Works = Modify<Bar, {
    foos: Array<FoosWithoutUnwanted>
}>
```

Even if this works, I think that declaring different Interfaces would be a better approach:

```
interface Nested {
    wanted: string;
}

interface NestedWithUnwanted extends Nested {
    unwanted: string;
}

interface Foo {
    nested: Nested
}

interface FooWithUnwanted {
    nested: NestedWithUnwanted
}

interface Bar {
    foos: Array<Foo>;
}

interface BarWithUnwanted {
    foos: Array<FooWithUnwanted>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```js
type Foo = {
  nested: {
    unwanted: string;
    wanted: string;
  };
};

type Bar = {
  foos: Foo[];
  untouched: number[];
};

type BarWithFoosArrayWithoutUnwanted = {
  [K in keyof Bar as Extract<K, "foos">]: {
    [KN in keyof Bar[K] as Extract<KN, "nested">]: Omit<
      Bar["foos"][number]["nested"],
      "unwanted"
    >;
  }[];
} & {
  [K2 in keyof Bar as Exclude<K2, "foos">]: Bar[K2];
};

const a: BarWithFoosArrayWithoutUnwanted = {
  foos: [{ nested: { wanted: "asdf" } }],
  untouched: [1, 2, 3],
};
```

There is a lot of hardcoded reference to the properties names though, so it might not be a very practical generic solution.