# Typescript: changing a property on window to optional?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The default TS type for `window.Notification` is `Notification`, but since the Web Notifications API has only 90% browser support, it should be `Notification | undefined`. I recently encountered a bug where I used `window.Notification` without checking if it's defined.

Is there a way to override properties on `window`, such as making them optional? I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    Notification?: Notification;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the definition of a property, but you can:

- create a new type with changed property
- change window type to that newly defined type.

See:

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45352250/1570854) to [How do you explicitly set a new property on `window` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709074/how-do-you-explicitly-set-a-new-property-on-window-in-typescript)
- [Overriding interface property type defined in Typescript d.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285211/overriding-interface-property-type-defined-in-typescript-d-ts-file)

```ts
import {Expect, Equal} from "type-testing";

declare global {
  type WindowModified = Window & Omit<typeof globalThis, 'Notification'> & {
   Notification?: Notification
  }
}
declare let window: WindowModified;
type CHECK = Expect<Equal<typeof window.Notification, Notification | undefined>>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwKIA8wFMDGMA0ckCOArgIYA2AvnAGZQQhwBEMAnhgLQzoDOMwAdgHNGAbgCwAKEkATLGRJR0cQWQgAjcoklw4rDHADqA6RADuAWQjTg1YOmlwAvIeNm4AMjgB5EMBgAePXQIamVVDTIAFQALYG48AHIAOQg%20W0wSPgh%20BIA%20Dy0JHTgUtOAMrP4AfgAuEtSbcszgbO04CkkOiVlMeUU4MnR4U1dTOqN%20EwsrRvtxCSC4AGEACSQlgGknfDQsAMJSMkC2YNCRybMAOlLGipb%20PBv05uy4AB84Ikn0W357XNyQA)

Comment: Turns out, it's even easier than that -- `global.d.ts`: `declare let Notification: typeof window.Notification | undefined;` I was looking at the above and thinking "the key thing there is redeclaring the `window` global...hey, wait, `Notfication` is a global...".

Comment: Oh wow, `declare let existingGlobalVar: Type` is evil but I guess it works.  It makes the compiler think that it's a *local* variable that shadows the global one, even though at runtime no such local variable exists.  Neat! ... but maybe the answer should mention that's what's happening; you're not changing the type of the global `window` but *shadowing* it.

Comment: @jcalz - Interestingly, it even works with `declare var ...`, which I was sure it wouldn't until I tried it.